# Property ngIf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, typescript

I keep getting this error in my component

`Property ngIf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template`

I tried other solutions found on this forum such as importing the `CommonModules`

But still getting the error.

I get the same error with `ngTemplateOutlet` as well

EDIT:

I'm using it here:

app.component.html

```
<div class="content" role="main" *ngIf="<expressionHere>">
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterOutlet} from "@angular/router";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterOutlet,   
    CommonModule,    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TestApp';
}
```

Comment: share your code pls to let us see where you are writing your ngif

Comment: updated code to show where I'm using it

Comment: can you please post code in your module.ts file for more clarity.

Comment: Added in the OP

Comment: maybe you need to post your `app.component.ts` too.

Comment: Added as well...

Comment: There is no sense to import `CommonModule` in appModule.ts and it should work without importing any other module.

Comment: Yeah it still shows that error, I even started a fresh project and same problem

Comment: maybe your IDE just needs an update. That was the solution for me at Angular version 16.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem.

In my case, this occurred while updating to Angular version 16.

I solved it by updating IDE. (Using Angular version 16 and Webstorm)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35132329)

Answer (score 0):

Why you have RouterOutlet in imports ? That imports array is for modules. Router-outlet is used in HTML like this.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Didn't you want to import RouterModule?

```
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)   
    CommonModule,    
  ],
```

And define your routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  // { path: 'path2', component: Component2 },
  // other routes...
];
```

btw: could you provide what you have in *ngIf that "expression" If the problem still persists.